# Set a new value after using regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a string that is equal to stringnum.

```
stringnum = "0007001369920090687073"
```

I need to use regex to grab the first 9 digits after the first 3 zeros. I am using this regex code `(?<=000)\d{9}` which gives me `"700136992"`

Now that I have this, I need to make a variable named  `result` equal to the regexed version of `stringnum`

```
result = 700136992
```

I have tried

```
result =  scanline.match(/^.{3}\K.{9}/)
```

but it gives me

```
=> #<MatchData "700136992>
```

The number is what I need, but I don't need the `#<Matchdata` stuff around it. How do I go about fixing this so that

```
result = "700136992"
```

If there is another way to set this value not using the `.match` method, I can do that as well. I'm new to regex so I'm not sure the best way to set a new value after regexing.

Comment: Try printing `result[0]`. I've followed examples here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/MatchData.html.

Comment: that gives me 700136992=>nil

Comment: thank you. I tried it wothout the print and it worked

Comment: glad to have helped!

Comment: `stringnum = 0007001369920090687073` needs quotes (`stringnum = "0007001369920090687073"`). That error is repeated.  `scanline` is presumably a typo. Please edit your question. As seen from the doc for the method [String#match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-match), `match` in `stringnum.match(<regular expression)` returns a `MatchData` object (an instance of the class  [MatchData](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html)), so you need to find a `MatchData` instance method to invoke on (send to) the `MatchData` object that returns the string you want.

Comment: If we take "...to grab the first 9 digits after the first 3 zeros." literally, and the string were `"07010369920090687073"`, the string to extract would be `"369920090"`? Is that what you want or do you mean `"...to grab the 9 digits after the first 3 digits"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string[regexp, capture = 0] → new_string or nil`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> When the Regexp argument `regexp` is given, and the `capture` argument is `0`, returns the first matching substring found in `self`, or `nil` if none found:

Here is a short demo:

```rb
stringnum = '0007001369920090687073'
result = stringnum[/(?<=000)\d{9}/]
puts result
# => 700136992
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/qNa2l7) online.

**NOTE**: The `string[regex, capture = 0]` method will return the first match, to get all matches as an array, use [`string#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
p stringnum[/^.{3}\K.{9}/)/]
```

Comment: Some elaboration on how this solves the question would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is wanted?

```
stringnum = "07010360009920090687"
```

**Extract the nine digits following the first three digits**

Why use a regular expression?

```
stringnum[3, 9]
  #=> "103600099"
```

See [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

**Extract the nine digits following the first three zeroes**

```
rgx = /\A(?:[1-9]*0){3}\K\d{9}/
```

```
stringnum[rgx]
  #=> "369920090"
```

**Extract nine digits that follow three zeroes at the beginning of the string**

```
rgx = /\A000\K\d{9}/
```

```
stringnum[rgx]
  #=> nil
```

```
"0000360009920090"[rgx]
   #=> "036000992"
```

(Similar to @Rajagopalan's answer.)

**Extract the nine digits following the first three zeroes in a row**

```
rgx = /(?<=000)\d{9}/
```

```
stringnum[rgx]
  #=> "992009068"
```

(@Wiktor's answer.)

Alternatively, `rgx = /000\K\d{9}/`.

---

Writing the regular expression `/^(?:[1-9]*0){3}\K\d{9}/` in *free-spacing mode* makes it self-documenting.

```
/
\A          # match the beginning of the string
(?:         # begin non-capture group
  [1-9]*0   # match >= 0 chars the char class followed by '0'
){3}        # end the non-capture group and execute it 3 times
\K          # reset the beginning of the match and discard all 
            # previously-matched chars
\d{9}       # match 9 digits
/x          # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

---

Similarly, `/\A000\K\d{9}/` can be written:

```
/
\A          # match the beginning of the string
000         # match 3 '0'
\K          # reset the beginning of the match and discard all 
            # previously-matched chars
\d{9}       # match 9 digits
/x          # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

---

`/(?<=000)\d{9}/` and `/000\K\d{9}/` can be written:

```
/
(?<=000)    # match '000' in a positive lookbehind
\d{9}       # match 9 digits
/x          # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
/
000         # match '000'
\K          # reset the beginning of the match and discard all 
            # previously-matched chars
\d{9}       # match 9 digits
/x          # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the question specifying that the `"000"` will necessarily be the first three characters.

Comment: @Chris, that's a good point. It's not clear what is being asked. I've modified my answer.

Comment: An additional thought that comes down to specifying the problem precisely: should `"000075623418"` yield `"075623418"` or does that count as _four_ zeroes followed by an _eight_ digit number and not qualify. In which case you'd want a pattern like: `[1-9]\d{8}`